# Open Georreferenced MODIS L2 atmospheric data in python

Tags: python, gdal, remote-sensing, georeferencing, modis

i'm working with a MOD04 (atmospheric product) but i don't know how to georrefence the image in Python.
I'll show an example of a code opening the Optical Thickness product

```
#==============================================================================
# MOD04 AOT PRODUCT
#==============================================================================
file_name04 = ("C:\MODIS\MOD04_L2.A2017112.1450.006.2017113014708.hdf")
MOD04 = gdal.Open(file_name04)
subdataset04=MOD04.GetSubDatasets()
meta04=MOD04.GetMetadata()
MODAOD = gdal.Open(subdataset04[63][0]) ###AOT PRODUCT
AOT = MODAOD.ReadAsArray()
meta04aot=MODAOD.GetMetadata()
AOT= AOT.astype(np.float32)
AOT[AOT == -9999] = np.nan
mult=float(meta04aot['scale_factor'])
add =float(meta04aot['add_offset'])
AOT = mult*(AOT-add)
```

The GeoTransform showed in the image notes that is not georrefenced:

```
    MODAOD.GetGeoTransform()
    >> (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

I try to set the boundaries using MODAOD.SetGeoTransform() with the north and west coordinates.

    XSize = MODAOD.RasterXSize
    YSize = MODAOD.RasterYSize

XSize
>> 135

YSize
>> 203

MOD04lat = meta04aot['GRINGPOINTLATITUDE.1']
MOD04lon = meta04aot['GRINGPOINTLONGITUDE.1']
MOD04lat,MOD04lon=MOD04lat.split(","),MOD04lon.split(",")

MOD04lat
>>: 
['-4.89502619820019',
 ' -7.98504122087105',
 ' -26.0833829669723',
 ' -22.6082546570904']

MOD04lon
>>: 
['-76.310463096777',
 ' -55.2650241843125',
 ' -58.3815019710174',
 ' -81.2664506382633']

north=np.float(meta04['NORTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE'])
west =np.float(meta04['WESTBOUNDINGCOORDINATE'])

 north
>>: -4.92184878405504
west
>>: -81.2587263920377

pixY_size = (abs(float(MOD04lat[0])-float(MOD04lat[2]))/YSize)
pixX_size = (abs(float(MOD04lon[3])-float(MOD04lon[2]))/XSize)

pixY_size
>> 0.1043761417180892

pixX_size
>> 0.1695181382758955

geo_transform=(float(MOD04lon[3]),pixX_size,0,float(MOD04lat[0]),0,

(pixY_size*-1))
MODOAOD.SetGeoTransform(geo_transform)
MODOAOD.SetProjection('GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,\
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],\
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]')
output=("C:\MODIS\MOD04_AOT.tif")
```

when i export the image i use this code

```
def save_raster ( output_name, dataset, raster_data, driver ,NaN_Value,arr_projection=None):
    if arr_projection is None:
        arr_projection=[]
    else:
        if str(type(arr_projection)) == "<class 'osgeo.gdal.Dataset'>":
            srs=arr_projection.GetProjectionRef ()
        else:
            srs = arr_projection
    """
    A function to save a 1-band raster using GDAL to the file indicated
    by ``output_name``. It requires a GDAL-accesible dataset to collect 
    the projection and geotransform.
    """
    # Open the reference dataset
    g = ( dataset )
    # Get the Geotransform vector

    if raster_data is False:
        raster_data=g.ReadAsArray()
    if type(raster_data) == tuple:
        raster_data = np.array(raster_data[0])
    if str(type(g)) == "<class 'osgeo.gdal.Dataset'>":
        geo_transform = g.GetGeoTransform ()
        x_size = g.RasterXSize # Raster xsize
        y_size = g.RasterYSize # Raster ysize
        srs = g.GetProjectionRef () # Projection
    elif str(type(g)) == "<class 'affine.Affine'>":
        geo_transform = (g[2],g[0],g[1],g[5],g[3],g[4])
        RastArr = raster_data
        x_size = int(RastArr.shape[1])
        y_size = int(RastArr.shape[0])
        #PROCESS RASTERIO NUMPY
    else:
        geo_transform = (g[1][2],g[1][0],g[1][1],g[1][5],g[1][3],g[1][4])
        RastArr = np.array(g[0])
        x_size = int(RastArr.shape[2])
        y_size = int(RastArr.shape[1])
    if raster_data.ndim > 2:
        raster_data=raster_data[0]
    NaN_rast = NaN_Value
    # raster_data[raster_data == NaN_rast] = 'NaN'
    raster_data[raster_data == NaN_rast] = np.NaN
    # Need a driver object. By default, we use GeoTIFF
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName ( driver )
    dataset_out = driver.Create ( output_name, x_size, y_size, 1, \
            gdal.GDT_Float32 )
    dataset_out.SetGeoTransform ( geo_transform )
    dataset_out.SetProjection ( srs )
    dataset_out.GetRasterBand ( 1 ).WriteArray ( \
            raster_data.astype(np.float32) )





save_raster(output,MODAOD,AOT,"GTiff",300000)
```

but when i open the image exported with python vs the image opened with qgis show that is the boundaries are not well georeferenced, because the MODIS image is not exactly rectangular

A picture taken from the hdf opening QGIS (well georefenced)
[image]

and the image exported with the python code

[image]

anyone know a pythonic solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution using gdal warp plus a thin-plate spline interpolation..

```
MOD04 = gdal.Open(file_name04)
MAOT=gdal.Open(MOD04.GetSubDatasets()[63][0]) #AOT EXAMPLE
gdal.Warp('C/directory/imagery.tif',MAOT,tps=True)
```

Comment: Does GDAL support the MODIS `HDF` files georeferencing? Is that python code? If so how the second line works? This space between variables is syntax error: `MAOT gdal.Open(...)`, no?

Comment: Mr. Che, i've missed the equal in the code line, so i fixed the code line. MAOT is a object created by the command gdal, open, so i added the equal ("=") between MAOT and gdal.Open